# Solving an optimization problem with variable powers

Tags: python, optimization, quadratic-programming

Can anyone point me to a tool (preferably in python or c++) to solve an optimization problem where in the objective has power fractions such as :

Maximize x1^0.2 + x2^ 0.3 + x3^0.4

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be possible in python with [scipy.optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#optimization-scipy-optimize)
Since it allows fractional exponentiation

```
4**0.5 = 2
4**0.2 = 1.3195079
```

and the objective function is defined as a plain python function.